# How can I make a QTreeView use up a large portion of the parent layout?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Edit: updated the minimal working example

i've got a QWidget window with only a menu bar and nothing else in it, except a QHBoxLayout with a label and a QTreeView widget. The tree view for now only contains 4 columns, but it will get more in the future and its already too small for the content within those columns, although I run resizeColumnToContents() for every column.
Checking the width() method of my tree view, i can see that it takes up only 100 pixels in width. The tree view receives its content from a model which gets updated dynamically, but I don't think that the display-related information of the view have something to do with the model its build upon.

Before posting the exact code, here's what I've tried so far:

- creating a QSizePolicy with horizontalPolicy set to MinimumExpanding and verticalPolicy set to Expanding
- tried to set a QSizePolicy with horizontalStretch set to maximum (255)
- tried to set a QSizePolicy with horizontalPolicy set to QSizePolicy.Ignored, which messed up my widget quite a bit, but apart from "moving" the tree view to the right the size didn't change.

A huge part of the problem might be the fact that i'm blind and cannot review my changes myself, I always have to ask someone to look at what I did, which gets frustrating really fast, but I hope that you can find an easy solution to my problem.

```
import random
from typing import Any, List

from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAction,
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QMenuBar,
    QSizePolicy,
    QTreeView,
    QWidget,
)


class Model(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setColumnCount(4)

        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Title", "Author", "Series", "Volume"])

        for i in range(100):

            row: List[QStandardItem] = []

            title: QStandardItem = QStandardItem("-" * random.randrange(100))
            title.setEditable(False)
            row.append(title)

            author: QStandardItem = QStandardItem("-" * random.randrange(100))
            author.setEditable(False)
            row.append(author)

            series: QStandardItem = QStandardItem("-" * random.randrange(100))
            series.setEditable(False)
            row.append(series)

            volume: QStandardItem = QStandardItem("--")
            volume.setEditable(False)
            row.append(volume)

            self.appendRow(row)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *args: Any,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.menu_bar = QMenuBar(self)
        self.file_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu("&File")

        act: QAction

        act = QAction("&Exit", self.file_menu)
        act.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file_menu.addAction(act)

        layout: QHBoxLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        libraries_view_label = QLabel("Books", self)
        layout.addWidget(libraries_view_label)
        self.libraries_model = Model(self)
        self.libraries_model.modelReset.connect(self._model_reset)

        self.libraries_view = QTreeView(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.libraries_view)
        self.libraries_view.setModel(self.libraries_model)
        libraries_view_label.setBuddy(self.libraries_view)

        policy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        policy.setHorizontalStretch(255)
        self.libraries_view.setSizePolicy(policy)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _model_reset(self) -> None:

        i: int

        for i in range(self.libraries_model.columnCount(QModelIndex())):
            self.libraries_view.resizeColumnToContents(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication([])

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Asking my sighted assistance I know that the columns are too small (the content often gets abbriviated with ...), and thats not optimal here. I thought the huge advantage of Qt is that you usually don't have to mess around with pixel sizes, but the widgets will resize and align automatically (which is kinda nice if you cannot see as you can imagine), but in that case I cannot get my tree view to become larger and take up more space although it really needs to do that. The only thing that should appear to the right of it at some point in the future is a media player like widget, but thats not gonna be huge and the tree view is free to use up everything else of the window, and I cannot see why it won't do that for now. Do I have to make the columns themselves larger to enlarge the entire tree view, and how am I supposed to do that without working with pixels?

Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  What are `Window`, `GroupedBooksModel` etc.?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Window is just a QWidget sub-class with a closed signal, nothing more, the model is just a model with some children, i'll update my post with some improvements to the code.

Comment: Are you sure that your `MainWindow` inherits only from `QWidget` class and not from `QMainWindow` class? Because if it inherited from `QMainWindow`, then you cannot use layouts to put stuff to the window. It would not work. You would need to use `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget()` method.

Comment: What about that "floating" QMenuBar? Please put more efforts in providing an *actual* and *useful* [mre]. Your code has lots of completely unnecessary parts (type hinting the `i` of a `for` loop? Seriously?) while missing the important ones (the inherited class? The other classes?). Please, focus on the important aspects.

Comment: I updated my minimal working example to be a copy-pasteable example which demonstrates my situation, the tree view filling about a fifth (?) of the screen although i'd like it to be larger since some columns still contain text which gets cut off due to not having enough space.

Comment: @ToniBarth wait, you asked about the tree view not "using a large portion of the layout", but now you're point out the *screen*. The code you provided properly shows the view occupying as much space as possible, and resizing the window actually expands the view as expected. Are you actually asking to make the *window* larger on start up? If that's the case, this has nothing to do with the layout, but with the size hint of the view. Start by adding `self.libraries_view.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QTreeView.AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow)`, which will use the contents of the view for the window size hint.

Comment: Then, if you want it to resize to contents since startup, do that in the `__init__`, or, better, just set it as default for the header: you can remove `_model_reset()` and just set `self.libraries_view.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)`, which will do the same at runtime and is usually fine for most cases (unless you have a very, very big model). Finally, that menu shouldn't be "floating" around, but added to the layout. Add `layout.setMenuBar(self.menu_bar)`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved the issue. I just want to make sure that I understand what you just changed. The problem wasn't the view, but the window around it? Or did it have something to do with the scroll area, which the tree view seems to inherit? Just trying to figure this out, not seeing things and having to work with descriptions of the on-screen behaviour confuses me quite a bit. Thank you alot, the tree view looks much better now, I just want to make sure that I understand the concepts so that I don't repeat my mistakes over and over again.

Comment: @ToniBarth it was a composite of different aspects. QAbstractScrollArea subclasses have a default size hint of 256x192, unless the size adjust policy is set and/or the class implements `sizeHint()` in different ways. Item views do that based on the current contents using different strategies (QTreeView uses the header for the horizontal hint). If none of that is set, the size hint of the view will be the default above, and the window will just be shown using the size hint of the layout, which computes recursively the size hint of all its items.

Comment: @ToniBarth I forgot to mention another important aspect: *all* new widgets always have a predefined size, which is 100x30 for widgets created with a parent argument and 640x480 for others, *unless* they have a minimum/maximum size that forces it. Widgets are not resized to their *final* size until they're actually shown, or their layout (or the layout in which they are added) is activated, so, until that moment, calling `size()` (including `width()` and `height()`) will *not* return the size that they will finally have in the shown UI.